# Haproxy node socket.io - WebSocket handshake error - Unexpected response code: 502

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, haproxy

I have configured my socket.io server behind haproxy using following configuration -

```
frontend http-in
  mode http
  bind *:9090

  acl is_websocket path_beg /prodSocket
  use_backend socket if is_websocket

backend socket
  timeout server 180s
  server 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1:9091
  server 148.251.76.84 148.251.76.84:9000
```

My Node socket.io server code -

```
var Server = require('socket io');
var io = new Server({'path': '/prodSocket'});

io.listen(9091);
console.log('started on  ' + 9091);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'connected' });
  socket.on('client', function (data) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnected', function(socket) {
     console.log(socket.id + " disconnected");
  });
});
```

My client code -

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:9090', {
  'path': '/prodSocket',
  'force new connection': false,
  'reconnection delay': 500,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10,
});
socket.emit('client', { my: 'data' });
socket.on('news', function (data) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

Errors -

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9090/prodSocket/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=cf1I2nsJrsksPpzfAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

I am not really understanding whats wrong here. Although this error, My server and clients are able to exchange the messages. But have to resolve this errror.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Haproxy Logs -

```
Jul 27 17:17:28 localhost haproxy[1332]: 127.0.0.1:42436 [27/Jul/2016:17:17:28.455] http-in socket/127.0.0.1 0/0/0/-1/15 502 205 - - SH-- 1/1/1/0/0 0/0 "GET /prodSocket/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=kZXRU_7vBf09aoE7AAAc HTTP/1.1"
Jul 27 17:17:28 localhost haproxy[1332]: 127.0.0.1:42436 [27/Jul/2016:17:17:28.455] http-in socket/127.0.0.1 0/0/0/-1/15 502 205 - - SH-- 1/1/1/0/0 0/0 "GET /prodSocket/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=kZXRU_7vBf09aoE7AAAc HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: It's amazing how often I see efforts to troubleshoot HAProxy connections without any mention of looking at the HAProxy **log**.  What does the log say, please?  Also, why are you testing with two backend servers instead of one, and why do the servers not have health checks configured?  How do you know which backend server didn't work?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for reply. I added the corresponding logs. Also I am deploying my node socket io on two boxes so testing it for multiple backends

Comment: Troubleshooting 101: don't test two varibles together until you've tested them separately.  Stick with one backend at a time.  `SH--` in your log suggests that your node server accepted the connection, then disconnected without sending a response.  Check the node server log.  HAProxy sent the 502 response because the backend didn't behave correctly.